# Bad Request 400 yandex-geocoding-api node.js

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Писал код для телеграм-бота на node.js. Потребовался геокодер Яндекс карт. Установил модуль XMLHttpRequest и стал для теста делать синхронный запрос.
Как не менял запрос, ответ один: 400 Bad Request
Взял пример, тоже самое. В чем проблема не понимаю, сам запрос несколько раз проверял, сверяя с https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest

Прилагаю код:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=Москва,+Тверская+улица,+дом+7", false);
request.send();
if (request.status != 200) {
  console.log(request.status + ': ' + request.statusText);
} else {
  console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
}
```

Comment: мимокрокодил: а `введите сюда код` должно быть в request.open("GET"`введите сюда код`) ? А если например сделать такой запрос request.open("GET", "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json", false); то он возвращает 200?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, вероятнее всего в некорректном запросе.
Современные браузеры слишком умные, они выполняют много вещей незаметно для пользователя. Например, кодирование параметров запроса. На сервере же, кроме Вас это делать некому.

При вводе запроса в адресную строку браузера, на сервер на самом деле отправляется:

> https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,+%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0,+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC+7

Для кодирования параметра в js есть функция [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var address = encodeURIComponent('Москва, Тверская улица, дом 7'); // <-- Тут!
request.open("GET", "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=" + address, false);
request.send();
if (request.status != 200) {
  console.log(request.status + ': ' + request.statusText);
} else {
  console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
}
```

Асинхронный пример с fetch:

```js
var address = encodeURIComponent('Москва, Тверская улица, дом 7');
fetch("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode="+address)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, сразу не догадался. Как только наберу нужное количество баллов, отмечу ответ.

Comment: `Как только наберу нужное количество баллов` - это не так работает. Но, в любом случае, добро пожаловать!